# Access state from parent - flutter

Tags: flutter

I try to create a basic notes app to study about flutter and I do not quite understand how to notify my `NotesContainer` that the button has been pressed. I tried to create a ref to it but the adding function is in the state class that I'm not sure how to reach.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final NotesContainer Notes = new NotesContainer();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('My Notes'),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(223, 175, 117, 1),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: (){
              Notes.add()
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Notes
    );
  }
}

class NoteData{
  String title;
  String content;

  NoteData(this.title, this.content);
  NoteData.noContent(t){
    title = t;
    content ='';
  }
}

class NotesContainer extends StatefulWidget{
  @override

  State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
    return new _NotesContainer();
  }

}

class _NotesContainer extends State<NotesContainer>{
  final _notes = <NoteData>[new NoteData('title','thing to do'), new NoteData('title2','thing to do2')];

  void add({String title='1'}){ //just to test adding 
    setState(() {
       _notes.add(new NoteData.noContent(title));
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return _buildNotesContainer();
  }

  _buildNotesContainer(){

    return new ListView.separated(
      itemCount: _notes.length,
      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(_notes[index].title), 
        );
      },
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    );
  }
}
```

I guess the solution is somehow exposing the _function in the `_NotesContainer` via the stateful `NotesContainer` class. I wonder if there is a more elegant solution for this.

Thanks, Or

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it makes more sense delegating the responsibility of adding a element further up in the widget tree. I modified your code to show how this works.

However, if you eventually get a deep widget tree and the children widgets require the _notes list, then I would recommend that you look into using a Inherited widget and add the _notes list to it, so you can access it without passing the state around too much.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Note the name change
class NotesPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _NotesPageState createState() => _NotesPageState();
}

class _NotesPageState extends State<NotesPage> {
  final List<NoteData> _notes = <NoteData>[NoteData('title','thing to do'), NoteData('title2','thing to do2')];

  void add({String title='1'}){ //just to test adding
    setState(() {
      _notes.add(NoteData.noContent(title));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text('My Notes'),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(223, 175, 117, 1),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: (){
                add();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: NotesContainer(notes: _notes)
    );
  }
}

class NoteData{
  String title;
  String content;

  NoteData(this.title, this.content);
  NoteData.noContent(t){
    title = t;
    content ='';
  }
}

class NotesContainer extends StatelessWidget{
  final List<NoteData> notes;

  const NotesContainer({Key key, this.notes}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return ListView.separated(
      itemCount: notes.length,
      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(notes[index].title),
        );
      },
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't want to put the states in the parent class to see how to handle it. I know that you can pass functions to children to handle parent states, but can you activate a function on the children state class from the parent?

Comment: Well the children state class is usually private, so I think that is rather difficult, and uncommon to do in Flutter. You may find these docs interesting: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive#managing-state

In regards to functions from children you can specify a VoidCallback or a Function(T) in the constructor of the widget. This is more like returning values from the children and using a function in the parent when these triggers. This will be similar to the properties in the widgets that work like property: () => someFunction

Comment: I see, so you have to put it in the top element. 
Actually, I would expect it to be easier. Because I will need to pass things around when things will become bigger and more complex. Thanks for the info

Comment: You can solve the passing state down problem by using InheritedWidgets. See https://medium.com/@mehmetf_71205/inheriting-widgets-b7ac56dbbeb1 and https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html . Child widgets can then access the values made available from the InheritedWidget. For example in the framework you have MediaQuery that is a inherited widget and can be accessed far down in the widget tree. F.ex: MediaQuery.of(context).size